# Advanced Custom Fields plugin : displaying a YouTube video

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

On my page, I have many fields text area fields containing text, and one WYSIWYG field containing a YouTube video (I need it to be WYSIWYG because otherwise only the URL of the video would show, not the video itself).

Problem: my text area fields have no tags other than br tags in them, whereas my WYSIWYG is full of p tags, creating layout misalignments.

If I remove p tags from the WYSIWYG field containing the video (using $strip = array('

','

'); echo str_replace($strip,'',$field);), then the iframe of the video becomes invisible, meaning it's there but it's gray in Firebug and doesn't show on the page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`wp_oembed_get`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get) and a textfield. You add the youtube url in the textfield.

Assuming the field name is `youtube_url`, your code will be something like:

```
if( get_field('youtube_url') ){
  $embed_code = wp_oembed_get( get_field('youtube_url') );
  echo $embed_code;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to display anything on my computer...

Comment: Try adding a real youtube url in the `wp_oembed_get` parameter

Comment: Just tried, doesn't display anything either.

Comment: Had made a regex script to strip the url and make my own embed... nice find

Answer (score 0):

you can create text type field in Advance custom field

```
$yt=get_field('youtube_url');//inside in loop
if( '' != $yt)
echo $GLOBALS['wp_embed']->autoembed( $yt );//youtube video iframe
```

Comment: Same comment: doesn't display anything on my computer.

Comment: did you define the text type field in acf with name 'youtube_url'?

Comment: No I did the other way around, I replace 'youtube_url' in your code by the name of the text field that I created and populated with a YouTube video URL.

Comment: ok, is this working know?`youtube_url` field type name in acf only was for example you can replace it by your own.